# iAds banner size against Google Ad Mob banner size iPhone6/6+

Tags: ios, admob, iad, iphone-6-plus

I see a difference between iAds banner size and Google Ad Mob banner sizes.
But the same should be equals.

A white square appears on the left of the iAds banner, so the banner is cropped on the right 'cause of the container size.

But for all the ads type I use the same size

```
_adsContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame),
                                     kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width, height);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I use now for iPad the `kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait` size.
Like this :

```
if ([UIDevice isIPad]) {
  _GADBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
} else {
  _GADBannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
}
```

(`[UIDevice isIPad]` is a custom category method ;) )